# ASP.NET Core WebAPI HttpClient in integration test

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, integration-testing

In my Web API, I have 3 methods:

1. val1 - set passed value to session
2. val2 - set passed value to session
3. diff - returns if both values in session are different

To create a client I use

```
var webAppFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
_httpClient = webAppFactory.CreateDefaultClient();
```

Then in integration tests, I use:

```
var responseVal1 = await _httpClient.PutAsync("/val1", content);
var responseVal2 = await _httpClient.PutAsync("/val2", content);

var responseDiff = await _httpClient.GetAsync("/diff");
```

Problem is that every requests of `PutAsync` or `GetAsync` generates new session on the server. Methods work from browser, but don't work from integration test because every request has own `HttpContext.Session`.

What am I doing wrong?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: `HttpClient` is not a browser, and AFAIK will not capture and share cookie/headers/etc between requests for you (cause it can be used in multithreaded environment to serve completely different requests), you need to that manually, i.e. get the session info from the first request and add it to the next one.

Comment: Every independent request is a new session. Unless you manually copy data onto the session manually from client side code OR you write code on server side to keep the session data in shared location and pick up existing data from every request, there is no way two independent request will share the data. Not only will they have unique session data, every session will be distinct.

This is why session state and state management was introduced in asp.net.

The moment you mentioned web API, sessions become irrelevant. If you are following REST standard, that is.